# CMYK to RGB converter not working both ways

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I'm trying to create a CMYK <-> RGB converter, which will let user move trackbars of the chosen profile (either CMYK or RGB - user might pick whichever trackbar he wants to use). However it works only in one way - depending on which method was written first. Below are my two converting methods:

```
        void sliderValuesCMYKtoRGB(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sliderR.Value = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - (sliderC.Value / 100)) * (1 - (sliderK.Value / 100)));
        sliderG.Value = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - (sliderM.Value / 100)) * (1 - (sliderK.Value / 100)));
        sliderB.Value = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - (sliderY.Value / 100)) * (1 - (sliderK.Value / 100)));
    }
    void sliderValuesRGBtoCMYK(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double sliderRValue, sliderGValue, sliderBValue;

        sliderRValue = sliderR.Value / 255F;
        sliderGValue = sliderG.Value / 255F;
        sliderBValue = sliderB.Value / 255F;

        sliderK.Value = ClampCmyk(1 - Math.Max(Math.Max(sliderRValue, sliderGValue), sliderBValue));
        sliderC.Value = ClampCmyk(((1 - sliderRValue - sliderK.Value) / (1 - sliderK.Value)) * 100);
        sliderM.Value = ClampCmyk(((1 - sliderGValue - sliderK.Value) / (1 - sliderK.Value)) * 100);
        sliderY.Value = ClampCmyk(((1 - sliderBValue - sliderK.Value) / (1 - sliderK.Value)) * 100);
        sliderK.Value = sliderK.Value * 100;

        sliderC.Value = Math.Round(sliderC.Value, 0);
        sliderM.Value = Math.Round(sliderM.Value, 0);
        sliderY.Value = Math.Round(sliderY.Value, 0);
        sliderK.Value = Math.Round(sliderK.Value, 0);
    }
```

And here you can see my main:

```
    public Calc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += calcValues_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += sliderValuesRGBtoCMYK;
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += sliderValuesCMYKtoRGB;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
```

All trackbar values are stored in config. Now here is my question - how do I make my converter work both ways? I tried multithreading but I'm not entirely sure I did everything correctly.

Comment: It would be easier to debug without complicating it with multiple threads.

Comment: "However it works only in one way"  How does it only work one way?  be a bit more descriptive about what is happening and what you expect.

Comment: Hmm, you have multiple Tick events with variables being used in multiple methods.  I can't see how that can possibly work.

Comment: @Sorceri my apology. What I meant by saying "one way" is that if I write sliderValuesRGBtoCMYK first it will only allow me to move trackbars responsible for RGB values, and CMYK values will change according to RGB values. It doesn't work if I move CMYK trackbars. They are "stuck" because of RGB sliders. However if I write sliderValuesCMYKtoRGB first it will work the other way.

Comment: @LarsTech please, forgive me my lack of knowledge. By saying that it won't work because of those ticks you mean that there is too many of them? As in they are interfering with each other? Am I supposed to create only one method responsible for Tick event?

Comment: @Losek It's pretty rare to add multiple methods to an event.  One method use the sliderC variable to update the SliderR.Value, and the other method uses the sliderR.Value to update the sliderC variable.